# Updating Dictionary in Mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb, dictionary, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a class that stores the following data:

```
public class User
{
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Pass { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>> Quests { get; set; }
}
```

New Users are instantiated with this:

```
await collection.InsertOneAsync(new User { Name = u, Pass = p, 
                     Quests = new Dictionary<string,Tuple<string,string>>() });
```

I know how to find and pull information from created documents, but I don't know how to push and save changes to documents. Most of the answers online are for the old Mongodb C# driver, so things like `Query` or `.save()` don't exist, or I didn't include the right packages into my program.

I want to be able to add and remove entries to the Dictionary and then save the changes to the document. Any suggestions?

Comment: Suggestion: RTFM :D http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/2.0/html/Methods_T_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollection_1.htm look for UpdateOneAsync

Comment: Doing so gives me Element `"` does not match any field or property of class Server.User. :D So RTFM doesn't really help

Comment: @Gusman That link seems to have gone poof.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what exactly you want. There are essentially two types of updates in MongoDB: you can perform an *atomic update*, or *replace the document*.

**Replacing the document is often easier**, because it allows you to use standard C# operations to perform modifications and it will re-evaluate generated properties and the like:

```
var user = new User { Name = "John Doe", Quests = 
   new Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>> { 
       { "hoho", new Tuple<string, string>("A", "A-Item") } } };
users.InsertOneAsync(user).Wait();
user.Quests = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>> { 
       { "hoho Modified", new Tuple<string, string>("B", "B-Item") } };
users.ReplaceOneAsync(p => p.Id == user.Id, user);
```

However, it is sometimes required to use atomic modifiers, like `$push`, `$pull`, `$set`, `$addToSet`, etc. because of concurrency concerns. I generally consider it a bad idea to perform complex operations on complex embedded objects this way, because there is a high likelihood the object's **consistency** (in the ACID sense, or *'object invariants'*) can't be checked.

Suppose a user should not be allowed to have more than 3 active quests at a time, who ensures this rule is observed? That is normally the code's responsibility, and complex invariants can't be checked by the database.

If you still want to use those atomic operators, I suggest you ask a new question because there it really depends on the details (the dictionary, by default, is serialized as a document, the tuple as an array, and they require different atomic modifiers in MongoDB). For example, to add a new item to the dictionary, use `$set`:

```
users.UpdateOneAsync(p => p.Id == user.Id, 
  Builders<User>.Update.Set("Quests.hoho Modified", 
     new Tuple<string, string>("B", "B-Item")));
```

Comment: As far I understand, *hoho* in *Quests.hoho* refers to a key in the dictionary, the value of which we wish to modify. However, I wonder if there's a neat way to **add** a new element to the dictionary. I.e. I want to modify the *Quests*'s contents, not one of the *Quest*'s key's content. I'm sure it's documented somehow. It's just my incompetency powered confusion that blinds me when I look at it. A pointer or two would be great.

Comment: I've used `Builders<Thing>.Update.Set(b => b.History,updatedHistory)` but that **replaces** the field value with the update. I'd like to **amend** to it but I'm not sure of the syntax. Horsing around with options like `ReturnDocument.Before` didn't work out as I'm not getting to the dictionary type in there.