# Update a Directory Value in Mongo C# Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm using MongoDB.Driver 2.10 and the following error is thrown:

> Unable to determine the serialization information for x =>
>   x.DeviceActions.get_Item(value(MyNamespace.DeviceManager+<>c__DisplayClass3_0).deviceAction.Key)

on the following line:

```
await userCollection.UpdateOneAsync(Builders<User>.Filter.Eq(s => s.Id, user.Id), updateDefinition);
```

The User class defines a Dictionary like so:

```
    [BsonElement("deviceActions")]
    [BsonDictionaryOptions(DictionaryRepresentation.ArrayOfDocuments)]
    public Dictionary<ObjectId, DeviceAction> DeviceActions { get; set; }
```

The problem is this line:

```
var updateDefinition = Builders<User>.Update.Set(x => x.DeviceActions[deviceAction.Key], DeviceAction.None);
```

Because `x.DeviceActions[deviceAction.Key]`can't be serialized to an update rule on the server, the exception is thrown. But how can I overcome this limitation?

With `DictionaryRepresentation.ArrayOfDocuments`, the document looks like this:

```
{
  "_id":{"$oid":"5dd6c1f2ec750390c76320c1"},
  "deviceActions":[
    {"k":{"$oid":"5df7bde2ca9bc28749096e4d"},"v":{"$numberInt":"1"}}
  ]
}
```

I want to update, not replace the document, because it is possible that different models are used and this would result in the document being truncated on replace. The answer in [Updating Dictionary in Mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29933188/updating-dictionary-in-mongodb) does not seem to deal with the {"k": "", "v": ""} structure of the document.

Furthermore, I want to update other properties on the user as well and the update should be atomic. So I think the filter needs to target the user in the first place.

Comment: are you trying to update a specific item in dictionary? is it supposed to be set to null each time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating Dictionary in Mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29933188/updating-dictionary-in-mongodb)

Comment: @Jawad yes, I need to update a specific item in the dictionary, where the key has a specified value. It will be set to the same value each time - DeviceAction.None
I don't think this other answer answers my question.

Comment: Didn't intend to mark this question as duplicate ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
            collection.UpdateOne(
                Builders<User>.Filter.Where(u =>
                    u.Id == userID &
                    u.DeviceActions.Any(a => a.Key == deviceAction.Key)),
                Builders<User>.Update.Set("deviceActions.$.v", DeviceAction.None)
                                     .Set(u => u.Name, "updated user"));
```

in order to update a nested document, you need to target the nested doc with an `elemMatch` which is what `u.DeviceActions.Any(a => a.Key == deviceAction.Key)` does in the filter. then with the update builder you're saying update the `v` field of the first result of the `elemMatch`.

here's a test program:

```js
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Options;
using MongoDB.Entities;
using MongoDB.Entities.Core;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class User : Entity
    {
        [BsonDictionaryOptions(DictionaryRepresentation.ArrayOfDocuments)]
        public Dictionary<ObjectId, int> DeviceActions { get; set; } = new Dictionary<ObjectId, int>();
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            new DB("test", "localhost");

            var user = new User();
            user.DeviceActions.Add(ObjectId.GenerateNewId(), 100);
            user.DeviceActions.Add(ObjectId.GenerateNewId(), 200);
            user.DeviceActions.Add(ObjectId.GenerateNewId(), 300);
            user.Save();

            var userID = user.ID;
            var key = user.DeviceActions.First().Key;

            DB.Update<User>()
              .Match(u =>
                     u.ID == userID &
                     u.DeviceActions.Any(a => a.Key == key))
              .Modify(b => b.Set("DeviceActions.$.v", 0))
              .Execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, that is great and a step in the right direction. But I want to update other properties on the user as well and the update should be atomic. Is this possible? I updated my question accordingly. What does the ```$``` operator do?

Comment: @pgross updated the answer with another chained `Set()` operator which will update the users `Name`. this is an atomic update operation. have a look at [this page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update-embedded-documents-using-multiple-field-matches) to understand the $ operator. it targets the first matching result of an `$elemMatch`. in the answer above, `u.DeviceActions.Any(a => a.Key == deviceAction.Key))` translates in to an $elemMatch.