# Add a key to an existing dictionary in MongoDb while replacing other fields using C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core-3.1

I want to update an existing document by amending a new value to a dictionary in it, while replacing other fields. We can see it as changing the current address while retaining a list of previous whereabouts.

The class constituting the information looks like this.

```
class Thing
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Location { get; set; }
  public Dictionary<string, string> History { get; set; }
}
```

I'm doing the update using the following code.

```
Thing update = ...;

Thing output = await _dbContext.Things
    .FindOneAndUpdateAsync(
        Builders<Thing>.Filter.Where(a => a.Name == update.name),
        Builders<Thing>.Update.Set(
            b => b,
            update
        ), ...
    );
```

Obviously, I need to explain to the DB how the update should be done: adding the current value of `Location` to `History` with e.g. timestamp or index as a key). Googling gave me [this blog](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollection_1_FindOneAndUpdateAsync__1.htm) suggesting alterantions on `ReturnDocument` like so.

```
Thing output = await _dbContext.Things
    .FindOneAndUpdateAsync(
        Builders<Thing>.Filter.Where(a => a.Name == update.name),
        Builders<Thing>.Update.Set(
            b => b,
            update
        ),
        new FindOneAndUpdateOptions<Thing>
        {
            ReturnDocument = ReturnDocument.Before
        }, ...
    );
```

Now, I guess (although not being sure) that I'm supposed to add the current value to the history. However, I can't even try that out because I'm unable to get to the `Thing` typed contents of the document. I can only obtain a BSON object and that gives me rather little. I've also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29940771/1525840) but it replaces the current value of a key in the dictionary instead of amending an additional one (also, I have a slight preference for lambda expressions if such is a viable option). The usual check at the [official docs](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.12/apidocs/html/R_Project_CSharpDriverDocs.htm) led only to more confusion. The following pseudo-code shows what I'm trying to get to.

```
...,
Builders<Thing>.Update.Set(
  b => b,
  new Thing
  {
    Name = b.name,
    Location = update.location,
    History = History.Add(DateTime.Now, b.Location)
  }
), ...
```

How should I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly, you need to store your dictionary key/value pairs as an array of documents in the db with the following attribute:

```cs
[BsonDictionaryOptions(DictionaryRepresentation.ArrayOfDocuments)]
public Dictionary<string, string> History { get; set; }
```

then you need to run an aggregation pipeline update with something like the following query:

```
db.Thing.updateOne(
    { Name: "NAME" },
    [
        {
            $set: { Location: "NEW LOC" }
        },
        {
            $set: {
                History: {
                    $concatArrays: [
                        "$History",
                        [{ k: "NEW DATE", v: "$Location" }]
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ])
```

unfortunately, the c# driver has no strongly typed support for pipeline updates nor operators like $concatArray. so you'll have to resort to a string based solution like so:

```cs
var filter = Builders<Thing>.Filter.Where(t => t.Name == "NAME");

var pipeline = PipelineDefinition<Thing, Thing>.Create(@"
{
    $set: {
        History: {
            $concatArrays: [
                '$History',
                [{ k: 'NEW DATE', v: '$Location' }]
            ]
        }
    }
}");

await collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, pipeline);
```

have a look at [this article](https://dev.to/djnitehawk/overcoming-the-limitations-of-mongodb-c-driver-1110) for an alternative solution for running advanced queries like this.

Comment: I'm not sure what the first code sample is for. As far I understand the contents of the second one, you run `UpdateOneAsync` with a filter for selecting the document and pipelining the concatenation of the arrays. What is the purpose of the first sample then?

Comment: @KonradViltersten the first is a mongodb shell query, which the c# driver should ultimately translate to in order to achieve your requirement.

Comment: Got it. So, in my case, I only need to focus on the latter, right? Also, you mention that I need to convert my dictionary to an array. Do you mean that I need to alter the class definition of my `Thing`?  For certain reasons, I'm not sure that's a feasible approach. We will need some kind of key to recognize the additions in the history. A plain, good, old list won't do.

Comment: @KonradViltersten no you just need to decorate your dictionary property with `[BsonDictionaryOptions(DictionaryRepresentation.ArrayOfDocuments)]` so that mongodb will store the data as an array of key/value pair objects in the db instead of a single object. only then you can use `$contactArrays` operator.